Tail-Recursive Binomial Coefficient Function in Java
I'm looking to implement a tail-recursive function to calculate the binomial coefficient of two numbers n and k. If k > n then 0 should be returned. Similarly if n == k or k == 0 it should return 1. I implemented it recursively like this but obviously this doesn't use the logic of a tail-call but I can't seem to figure out how to connect the two calculations into one recursive call. Any help would be greatly appreciated, also an explanation how to go from a normal recursive function to the tail-recursive implementation. Thanks!
    public static long binomCoeffRecursive(int n, int k) {
        // TODO: Implement binomCoeff recursively.
        if (n == k) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (k > n) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (k == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return binomCoeffRecursive(n-1, k-1) + binomCoeffRecursive(n - 1, k);
    }


c(n,k) = c(n-1,k-1)+c(n-1,k) = c(n-2,k-2)+  c(n-2,k-1)+c(n-2,k-1) +c(n-2,k) = ... trace it back up to the 0,0 source. now reverse the direction. this gives you your iterative algorithm which you can code as a loop, calculating these rows in the "Pascal triangle".

I don't think a loop is what's asked for, and even if you had a function returning rows -- that's at least a recursive algorithm with only one recursive call, but it's not obvious to me that you can do it as a tail-recursive call, since you need to perform operations after getting the previous row to get the next row.

@LouisWasserman a loop can naturally be written as a tail-recursive function. here, all you need is one last row. and you don't need all of it. you only need one element in the final row; two in the one-before-last, etc. these rows trace a rhombic figure in the Pascal triangle. this row is your loop variable.

@LouisWasserman the way to avoid the problem you mention at the end of your comment, is to "reverse the direction". to calculate the next row from the one you get as the argument, before calling self with that next row, as the final action. OR, in case it was the target row, just return the final result.

All right, I buy that, though I'm not sure I buy that it can reasonably be called a translation of this algorithm as opposed to a different formula.

... IOW we don't get the previous row from recursive call, as is usual in recursion, but rather we get it ready-made as an argument, and give the next row to the recursive call - as is usual in TR-coded iteration. That's what I wanted to write there, above. cc @LouisWasserman

TCR in java.

to implement a tail-recursive function

java does not apply TCR and is unlikely that it ever will; it was part of 'near future java plans' for quite a while, has since been thoroughly investigated, and the benefits do not outweigh the costs of delivering it. It complicates bookkeeping for stacks, for example - that's just one example of where there's a cost associated.
Hence, no matter what you write here, you will not end up with a TCR version because neither javac nor the JVM (java) knows what that is.
Various other languages do have it, and perhaps some that run on the JVM have it, so you could look there.
In principle you can rewrite any recursive algorithm in one that isn't recursive and uses a loop instead; when TCR can apply, that loop concept doesn't require state.
Think about it like that and that should help.
Your specific code
We're now going to talk hypotheticals. Let's say your program was written in qava, which is exactly like java except it does have TCR. Would your app be TCRed in qava?
No, because that is not compatible with the needs of TCR.
Imagine you rewrote this as a loop, then, when 'looping' to end up producing what binomCoeffRecursive(n-1, k-1) would produce, you need to remember someplace that you also need to figure out what binomCoeffRecursive(n - 1, k) would produce and add that.
TCR requires that your app ends in literally just return self(args). Not return self(args) + self(more args);.
That's the 'trick' you need to work on. There is no formulaic way to translate some non-TCR recursive code into TCR-able recursive code. Some jobs can't be rewritten like that all (if there's no way to avoid having state for each call and you have to do at least 2, then TCR is not possible; TCR can run forever, any algorithm that requires infinite memory thus couldn't fit in TCR unless you manage to shift the endlessly growing thing into the shape of a parameter).
As an alternative example, here is a trivial fibonacci in recursive form:
static int fib(int n) {
  if (n == 0) return 0;
  if (n == 1) return 1;
  return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}

it's recursive, but not TCRable. Here's a TCRable one:
static int fib(int n) {
  return fib0(n, 0, 1);
}

private static int fib0(int n, int a, int b) {
  if (n == 0) return a;
  if (n == 1) return b;
  return fib0(n - 1, b, a + b);
}

It's completely different, appears to approach the problem mostly from the other direction (we build 'up' from 0/1 instead of building 'down'). That should do a few things:

make intuitive to you that there is no simple 'recipe' for turning non-TCR recursive algorithms into TCR recursive algorithms.
What TCR algorithms look like.


Thank you, I didn't choose to implement it in a tail-recursive way it was just a practice assignment I got from uni. We also had to do fibonacci and that was more intuitive for me I guess because it's about "counting up" instead of "counting down". Nevertheless, thank you for the explanation!

"There is no formulaic way to translate some non-TCR recursive code into TCR-able recursive code." well, actually, yes there is. it's CPS transform followed by Defunctionalization.  "any algorithm ... thus couldn't fit in TCR unless you manage to shift the endlessly growing thing into the shape of a parameter" and yes, you always can. your computer does it too, running that recursive code. you just need to make its state explicit in your code's values and structures.

You can't get a tail recursive implementation with that formula because you cannot "connect the two calculations into one recursive call" like you're hoping for.  Tail recursion is only possible when there's only one recursive call, and you can't fuse them together.
There are tail-recursive implementations for calculating binary coefficients, however, that only use one recursive call.  An iterative implementation suitable for conversion to tail recursion can be found, for example, in Guava.  (Disclosure: I wrote it.)  That depends on the multiplicative formula.

Okay, so if I want to implement tail-recursion I need to have a formula dependent on one operation?

That's correct.  However, rzwitserloot is also correct that tail recursion is not meaningfully implemented in Java: there is no tail call optimization; there is no benefit to writing in a tail-recursive style.

the benefit to writing tail-recursive code is to have it as intermediate step before re-writing it as a loop. and you can always transform any recursive code into tail-recursive one. yes, "that formula" on its own isn't TR, but saying "you can't fuse them together" isn't true. there are multiple ways to transform that code into TR one.   I'm surprised by this answer.

I wouldn't call CPS or the like a successful application of tail recursion, which your other comments seem to indicate is what you're getting at.  If what you're doing is just implementing something that executes equivalently to real recursion, I don't think that's worth counting.

no, this is not what it indicated. I was responding to a specific claim that "there is no formulaic way" by giving that general, formulaic way.  but here, a specific, much easier way is memoization followed by its reverse the DP, followed by what I described in the other comment under the Q itself. as to the "worth counting", yes it is worth it, to avoid stack exhaustion if that's what you're faced with.

If you want an efficient implementation that does not grow the stack, you are out of luck, java does not do the tail-call optimization as explained by @rzwitserloot.
If you just want to satisfy the 'last call to itself' rule for whatever reason, you could do something like
public static long binomCoeffRecursive(int n, int k) {
    return binomCoeffRecursiveInternal(n, k, 0);
}

private static long binomCoeffRecursiveInternal(int n, int k, long offset) {
    if (n == k) {
        return 1+offset;
    }
    if (k > n) {
        return offset;
    }
    if (k == 0) {
        return 1+offset;
    }
    offset += binomCoeffRecursiveInternal(n-1, k-1, 0);
    return binomCoeffRecursiveInternal(n - 1, k, offset);
}

which is a mix of ordinary and tail recursion.

"ordinary" i.e. "non-tail" mixed with "tail" recursion is still fully "non-tail" recursion.
